# How to run this PHP command?

Tags: php, web, vps

I have php code which cannot be run.

```
$add_file_location = dirname(__FILE__);
$shell_cmd = "php {$add_file_location}/test2.php mytest > /dev/null &";
shell_exec($shell_cmd);
```

How can I run the code so it can run test2.php file on web hosting or vps.

Comment: Why cannot it be run? Are you getting any errors or messages? It's possible that your host has, for good reasons, disabled the `shell_exec` function.

Comment: If I run echo shell_exec("ls"); it list all the file so it means shell_exec function is enable

Comment: Okay, are you getting any errors? Try removing the `> /dev/null` section of the command and capturing the return value of `shell_exec` so you can see what the output is. You may also need to change `php` to the full path to the PHP binary, e.g. `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: `X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: ` I got that for output.

Comment: If that's the case, before you do anything else you need to upgrade (or ask your host to upgrade) PHP. Version 4.4.9 has not been supported since 2008 and will probably be riddled with security holes.

Comment: I got this error `Warning: shell_exec(): Unable to execute '/usr/bin/php /home3/webku/public_html/flex/test2.php' in /home3/webku/public_html/flex/test1.php on line 4`

Comment: You could try `php5` to run the correct PHP intepreter.

Answer (score 0):

You *do not* want to be using shell_exec for this.

```
$file_loc = dirname(__FILE__);
require($file_loc.'/test2.php');
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: But I want to run that test2.php

Comment: `require` is not functionally equivalent to `shell_exec`, they do two completely different things.

Comment: Nevertheless, require will force the execution of an external php file.

Comment: True, but you can't pass command line arguments to that file like you can with `shell_exec` (and as the OP appears to want to do).

Comment: I don't want to include that external php file. But I want to execute the code inside the external file.

Comment: @pwaring- I would query that whole line of using php, but if that's what the OP *really* wants...

Comment: It does actually make sense in certain situations, for example I've been forced to use `exec` to run PHP scripts in the past because of per-script memory constraints.